# Как сделать Slide Banner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки, хочу у Вас спросить, как сделать slide banner своими руками. Я только начинаю практику на JQuery, поэтому, не зная всех тонкостей, не хочу писать костыльный код, а по сим обращаюсь к Вам с такими вопросами:

1. Какие настройки необходимо сделать в таблице стилей(или не только в стилях), чтобы баннер корректно отображался при адаптивном дизайне.
2. Какие плагины стоит использовать (но не такие, что подключил, а он сам за тебя всё сделал), или же подключить JQueryUI, или же всё можно реализовать, используя JQuery?

P.S. Можно в ответах, не сам код, а его описание, так как очень хочу сам всё написать)

Comment: Одними подсказками вы будете неделю лепить, имхо без разборки чужих примеров не обойтись, как пример смотрите [сюда](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1050) и пишите по его примеру. Одного jquery ядра достаточно, для адаптивности соответствующего css для начала достаточно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за пример